# c# mvc html.raw is allowing cross site scripting attack

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I have used MVC @Html.Raw element to save URL into a javascript variable. But this makes my URL vulnerable for an XSS attack.

If someone puts query string as: ?budget=0-8";alert('a')//

And I do: var url = "@Html.Raw("domain/?budget=0-8";alert('a')//")", it alerts 'a' on user browser.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: **1.** Why use `@Html.Raw()` in the first place? **2.** Constraint your input type: If `budget` is expecting a range, parse it to 2 `int`s in the controller level, or use `int budgetStart` and `int budgetEnd`. In short, don't allow arbitrary `string` data to get into your view. If your action method is expecting a `string`, parse it into a stricter type before it reaches the view.

Comment: If you use `@Html.Raw()` you really should sanitize input first. Either manually or look into some external library to help.

Comment: @haim770: We are using @Html.Raw() to pass on query string as it is. If we don't do that, we get encoded characters. Is there any alternate of @Html.Raw() for such cases?

Comment: @haim770: If I use, @HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode("?budget=0-8";alert('a')//"), it works fine as this string gets encoded. But is it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

### .Net Core

If your goal is to have this as a variable in javascript, you should use `@Json.Serialize()` from your view with `JsonSerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml`.

Example:

```
<script>
    var myQueryParams = @Json.Serialize(new { url = Model.SomeUserProvidedString }, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() {StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml });
</script>
```

`myQueryParams.url` will be an html-escaped URL and prevent XSS through `Model.SomeUserProvidedString`.

---

### .Net Framework MVC

Framework MVC doesn't have `@Json.Serialize()` - you can recreate this function if your package includes Newtonsoft.Json. This is based on the [open source .Net Core implementation of `@Json`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/b196708a3e0bca4820f2002e063fabe979afde1b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/JsonHelper.cs)

```
HtmlString SerializeToJson(object obj)
{
    var jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { StringEscapeHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml })
    return new HtmlString(jsonString);
}
```

Comment: are you sure? I can't find anything like Json.Serialize?

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? I've been using `Json.Serialize` in MVC core but it's just a wrapper around Newtonsoft.Json so it can be recreated

Comment: MVC4 Asp.net, not the core

Comment: If your package has Newtonsoft.Json you can recreate the function - see my edited answer.